# Low-voltage cabling through ceiling? Up to code?

Tags: electrical, low-voltage

I'm making a CCTV / Router "space", and was thinking of just drilling a hole in the ceiling and installing a gang box on the attic side of the ceiling. Are there any codes that refer to this kind of work? Perhaps this violate any codes? (I'm in FL just in case) To make it clear, no line power will be in this junction box.. I'll leave that installation to an electrician.

Comment: You're asking about putting a junction box in the ceiling, mounted as one would be in a wall? Or just running a LV cable through a small hole in the ceiling?

Comment: Actually, I would be interested in both of those solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For low voltage (CCTV, Cat6, coax, audio, etc.) you can use a boxless bracket like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000W09PQI).

Your local Code could be anything so you should check that out with your municipality and state authorities.

Good luck!

Comment: However, even if not required, you can use a box. Exceeding the minimum requirements is fine, and does not cost very much in this case.

Comment: I actually ended up calling a house inspector, and he indicated that where I'm at there's no "actual" codes for low-voltage. So I guess what he meant that as long as it's nothing stupid...